# Security Framework memory leak using ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, memory-leaks

I'm experiencing memory leaks when opening a p12 certificate for an ASIHTTPRequest. Here is my code to get the certificate:

```
- (SecIdentityRef)getClientCertificate {
    SecIdentityRef identityApp = nil;
    NSString *thePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myCert" ofType:@"p12"];
    NSData *PKCS12Data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:thePath];
    CFDataRef inPKCS12Data = (__bridge CFDataRef)PKCS12Data;
    CFStringRef password = CFSTR("myPassword");
    const void *keys[] = { kSecImportExportPassphrase };
    const void *values[] = { password };
    CFDictionaryRef options = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, values, 1, NULL, NULL);
    CFArrayRef items = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
    OSStatus securityError = SecPKCS12Import(inPKCS12Data, options, &items);
    CFRelease(options);
    CFRelease(password);
    if (securityError == errSecSuccess) {
        NSLog(@"Success opening p12 certificate. Items: %ld", CFArrayGetCount(items));
        CFDictionaryRef identityDict = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items, 0);
        identityApp = (SecIdentityRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(identityDict, kSecImportItemIdentity);        
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error opening Certificate.");
    }
    return identityApp;
}
```

As you can see here it produces memory leaks:
[image]

Alternatively, this other function (basically the same) produces other types of memory leaks:

```
- (SecIdentityRef)getClientCertificate2 {
    SecIdentityRef identityApp = nil;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *thePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myothercert.p12"];

    NSData *PKCS12Data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:thePath];
    NSLog(@"PKCS12Data length is %i", [PKCS12Data length]);
    CFDataRef inPKCS12Data = (__bridge CFDataRef)PKCS12Data;

    CFStringRef password = CFSTR("randomgenerated");
    const void *keys[] = { kSecImportExportPassphrase };
    const void *values[] = { password };
    CFDictionaryRef options = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, values, 1, NULL, NULL);
    CFArrayRef items = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
    OSStatus securityError = SecPKCS12Import(inPKCS12Data, options, &items);
     CFRelease(options);
    //CFRelease(password);
    if (securityError == errSecSuccess) {
        NSLog(@"Success opening p12 certificate. Items: %ld", CFArrayGetCount(items));
        CFDictionaryRef identityDict = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items, 0);
        identityApp = (SecIdentityRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(identityDict, kSecImportItemIdentity);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error opening Certificate.");
    }
    return identityApp;
}
```

which produce these memory leaks:
[image]

What is it that is causing these memory leaks? The code works fine for opening the p12 files but I need to fix the memory leaks. Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

> **EDIT**

With suggested changes I still receive memory leaks:

```
- (SecIdentityRef)copyClientCertificate2 {
SecIdentityRef identityApp = nil;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *thePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"cert.p12"];

NSData *PKCS12Data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:thePath];
NSLog(@"PKCS12Data length is %i", [PKCS12Data length]);


CFStringRef password = CFSTR("randomgenerated");
const void *keys[] = { kSecImportExportPassphrase };
const void *values[] = { password };
CFDictionaryRef options = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, values, 1, NULL, NULL);
CFArrayRef items = NULL;
OSStatus securityError = SecPKCS12Import((__bridge CFDataRef)PKCS12Data, options, &items);
 CFRelease(options);
//CFRelease(password);
if (securityError == errSecSuccess) {
    NSLog(@"Success opening p12 certificate. Items: %ld", CFArrayGetCount(items));
    CFDictionaryRef identityDict = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items, 0);
    identityApp = (SecIdentityRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(identityDict, kSecImportItemIdentity);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error opening Certificate.");
}
CFRetain(identityApp);
return identityApp;
```

}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're leaking `items`. You Create it but never Release it. You shouldn't be creating it in the first place. `SecPKCS12Import` returns `items` by reference. You don't pass it an existing one; it passes *you* one. This should be:

```
CFArrayRef items = NULL;
```

You'll also need to call `CFRetain()` on `identityApp` to hold onto it (since it's only currently retained by the array. Therefore, your method needs to be called `copyClientCertificate2` and you need to `CFRelease()` its result when you're done with it.

Side note: Never preface a method with "get" unless it returns its result by reference. That's what "get" means in ObjC. For example:

```
- (BOOL)getName:(NSString **)name;
```

You have another really dangerous piece of code in here:

```
NSData *PKCS12Data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:thePath]; // (1)
CFDataRef inPKCS12Data = (__bridge CFDataRef)PKCS12Data;              // (2)
...
OSStatus securityError = SecPKCS12Import(inPKCS12Data, options, &items); // (3)
```

ARC is free to release `PKCS12Data` immediately after line (2). If you build this in Release mode, I would expect it to crash. The correct solution here is to get rid of `inPKCS12Data`, and perform the `__bridge` cast at line (3).

---

EDIT:

It is very important that you understand how to manage Core Foundation objects if you're doing this kind of work. First, study the Create Rule linked below. Then, the point of calling the method `copy…` was to indicate that the caller is responsible for calling `CFRelease` on the returned object. It would look like this:

```
SecIdentityRef identity = [self copyClientCertificate2];
... Do what you need to do with identity ....
CFRelease(identity);
```

Since you never use `self` in `copyClientCertificate2`, it may make more sense to you to make it a function, so that it looks like other Core Foundation functions:

```
SecIdentityRef identity = MYSecIdentityCopyClientCertificate();
... Do what you need to do with identity ....
CFRelease(identity);
```

Note the word `Copy` in the function name.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try and let you know

Comment: I implemented your suggestions (look at my edit) but still have memory leaks. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

Comment: When are you releasing the returned `SecIdentityRef`? Are you retaining it elsewhere? Are you still leaking the same object (is it a `SecIdentityRef`? A `CFArrayRef`?)

Comment: I'm doing CFRetain on the SecIdentityRef as you suggested. This is done just before I return it on the function. How can I determine the leaked object from the whole list? Is it the ones that have an underscore before the name like _NSCFArray?

Comment: Yes, but when are you *releasing* the SecIdentityRef? You must balance your retains and releases. This is Core Foundation. It follows the Create Rule: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html. An object listed in the Leaked list indicates that the object cannot be reached from any known pointers (so it is "lost"). The stack trace tells you where the memory was allocated; this does not tell you where your mistake was. You must make sure that you're following the Create Rule on all Core Foundation objects.

Comment: I guess I'll take the SecIdentityRef (identityApp) out of this method make it a global variable for me to release when I'm done with it. I'm pretty sure I can't release it inside this method if it's the return value of the method.

Comment: It does not need to be a global; you need to release it after the *caller* is done with it. That's why the method needs to be called `copy...`. This indicates that the caller is responsible for releasing the object.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39449/discussion-between-gabcas-and-rob-napier)

Comment: Thanks, I simply took the workings out of the method and released all objects after they were used.  I couldn't get the caller to release them :$
Anyways, no more memory leaks!